# Asp.Net HttpBrowserCapabilities contains Information from other Page

Tags: asp.net

I have two web pages. Page A has to run in IE compatibility mode, Page B not. You can go from Page A to Page B via a Hyperlink. When clicking on this Hyperlink some BusinessLogic is processed and then uses Response.Redirect().

The problem: On Page B i need to get the current IE version of the browser. But after the Response.Redirect() i get the IE Version of the compatibility mode and not the browser itself. I use System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities to get the browser version.

Comment: send it with get parameters on url

Comment: This is by design, compatibility mode changes the useragent string the browser is sending with the request. Maybe split the application in two and have one run in compatibility mode and the other not?

Comment: Page A and B are two different applications on different servers. Is there a way to avoid sending the useragent string from compatibility mode  to Page B when using Response.Redirect()?